# How to deploy the same compose in different stacks and adapt container names automatically?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to design a `docker-compose.yml` file that will allow me to easily launch environments to develop inside of. Sometimes I would like to have 2 or more of these up at the same time but doing it naively I get `ERROR: for pdb  Cannot create container for service pdb: Conflict. The container name "/pdb" is already in use by container ...` (even if they are on different stacks).

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  pdb:
    hostname: "pdb"
    container_name: "pdb"
    image: "postgres:latest"

(...other services...)
```

Is there a way to automatically name these in a distinguishable but systematic way? For example something like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  pdb:
    hostname: "${stack_name}_pdb"
    container_name: "${stack_name}_pdb"
    image: "postgres:latest"

(...other services...)
```

---

EDIT: Apparently this is a somewhat service specific question so here is the complete compose file just in case...

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  rmq:
    hostname: "rmq"
    container_name: "rmq"
    image: "rabbitmq:latest"
    networks:
      - "fakenet"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
    healthcheck:
      test: "rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping"
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3

  pdb:
    hostname: "pdb"
    container_name: "pdb"
    image: "postgres:latest"
    networks:
      - "fakenet"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ******
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
    volumes:
      - "./deploy/pdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "./data/dbase:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  workenv:
    hostname: "aiida"
    container_name: "aiida"
    image: "aiida_workenv:v0.1"
    expose:
      - "8888" # AiiDa Lab
      - "8890" # Jupyter Lab
      - "5000" # REST API
    ports: # local:container
      - 8888:8888
      - 8890:8890
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - "./data/codes:/home/devuser/codes"
      - "./data/aiida:/home/devuser/.aiida"
    depends_on:
      pdb:
        condition: service_healthy
      rmq:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - "fakenet"
    environment:
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      PSQL_HOST: "pdb"
      PSQL_PORT: "5432"
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"

networks:
  fakenet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't manually set `container_name:` at all.  Compose will automatically assign a name based on the current [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).  Similarly, you don't usually need to set `hostname:` (RabbitMQ is one extremely specific exception, if you're using that).

If you do need to publish ports out of your Compose setup to be able to access them from the host system, the other obvious pitfall is that the first [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) number must be unique across the entire host.  You can specify a single number for `ports:` to let Docker pick the host port, though you'll need to look it up later with [`docker-compose port`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/).

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  pdb:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    # no hostname: or ports:

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      PGHOST: pdb
    ports:
      - 3000 # container-side port, Docker picks host port
```

```sh
docker-compose -p myname -d up
docker-compose -p myname port app 3000
```

Comment: Hey @David Maze, thanks for the reply, the `PGHOST: pdb` example helped me understand a bit more how to handle that service. So I don't need to expose ports for the containers to communicate with one another, only for externa access? However, I do happen to be using RabbitMQ as a second service =( [see updated post]. What is the problem with that? Do I need any care when selecting the hostname? My setup currently works for 1 deployment but I didn't do anything special...

Comment: Usually a container sees its container ID as its hostname.  RabbitMQ, specifically, stores data in a directory named after the hostname, so if you restart RabbitMQ in a new container with a different hostname, it won't find the old container's data.  So specifically for RabbitMQ you need to set `hostname:` to some fixed string, but it doesn't matter much what it is, and it's not related to connectivity between containers at all.

Comment: Follow up question: if I let docker choose the host ports, how do I know which ones were chosen? For example, I need to pass them to my other service to interact both with postgres and rmq, and so I can check notebooks that are running inside of it from outside.

Comment: `docker-compose port` tells you.